# Showing/hiding of a widget on focus at another widget

Tags: pyqt6, class-attributes, focusout, focusin

I would like "Button" object to disappear when "Target" object is not in focus (for example, when object "Secondary" is focused) and to re-appear when "Target" is in focus again. So, "Target" focused = "Button" visible. In other words, in the code below there are two lines, "Line A" and "Line B", that I would like to implement in the code.

`

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit


class Wn(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.target = Target("Target", self)
        self.target.setFixedSize(400, 60)
        self.target.move(50, 50)
        self.secondary = QLineEdit("Secondary", self)
        self.secondary.setFixedSize(400, 60)
        self.secondary.move(50, 150)
        self.button = QPushButton("Appears @ Target focused. Disappears @ target not focused", self)
        self.button.setFixedSize(400, 60)
        self.button.move(50, 250)


class Target(QLineEdit):

    def focusInEvent(self, k):
        print("The target is in focus: Button should be shown")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        # Wn.button.setHidden(False)                             # Line A

    def focusOutEvent(self, p):
        print("The target is out of focus: Button should be hidden")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        # Wn.button.setHidden(True)                              # Line B


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wn = Wn()
wn.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a signal and emit it whenever the focus changes, then connect it with the button's `setVisible()`.

```py
class Wn(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.target.focusChanged.connect(self.button.setVisible)


class Target(QLineEdit):
    focusChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def focusInEvent(self, k):
        super().focusInEvent(k)
        print("The target is in focus: Button should be shown")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.focusChanged.emit(True)

    def focusOutEvent(self, p):
        super().focusOutEvent(p)
        print("The target is out of focus: Button should be hidden")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.focusChanged.emit(False)
```

Alternatively, you can just install an event filter on the line edit and look for `FocusIn` and `FocusOut` events.

Note that you should *always* call the base implementation of event handler overrides, unless you *really* know what you're doing, otherwise you might prevent proper default behavior of the object.

Also, [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) should always be used instead of fixed geometries. Since the visibility of a widget also nullifies its size in the layout and adapts the other widgets managed by it (similarly to `display: none` in CSS), you should probably consider using [`setRetainSizeWhenHidden()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#setRetainSizeWhenHidden) for the widget's size policy:

```py
class Wn(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        # create a proper layout and add widgets
        # ...
        policy = self.button.sizePolicy()
        policy.setRetainSizeWhenHidden(True)
        self.button.setSizePolicy(policy)
```